# Correlation coefficient of matrices

Tags: c++, visual-c++

would someone be able help me please, as I'm getting errors on this code and I don't know where it is going wrong. I am getting the following:
errors C2059: syntax error : 'return', 
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body,
error C2039: 'rtn' : is not a member of 'corr_coefficient'
see declaration of 'corr_coefficient'
Thank you.

```
using namespace std;

class corr_coefficient
{
    matrix x, y;
    double sum, C, corr[5];
    int j;  
public:
    double calc_mu(matrix x, int j=0);
    double calc_covariance(matrix x, matrix y, int j); 
    double calc_correlation();
    double StandardDeviation(matrix a, int j=0);
    double return(int i){return corr[i];
    };
    corr_coefficient(matrix x, matrix y);
    };

double corr_coefficient::calc_mu(matrix x, int j)
{
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<C; i++)
    {
        sum = sum+x(i,j);
    }
    return sum/C;
}

double corr_coefficient::calc_covariance(matrix x, matrix y, int j)
{
    double mux=calc_mu(x,0); 
    double muy=calc_mu(y,j); 
    sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<C; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+(x(i,0)-mux)*(y(i,j)-muy);
    }
    return sum/(C-1); 
}
double corr_coefficient::StandardDeviation(matrix a, int j)

{
    double mua=calc_mu(a,j); 

    sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<C; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+((a(i,j))-mua)*((a(i,j))-mua);
    }
    return sqrt(sum/(C-1));
}
corr_coefficient::corr_coefficient(matrix x, matrix y)
{
    C=35;
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        corr[j]=calc_covariance(x, y, j)/(StandardDeviation(x, 0)*StandardDeviation(y, j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
double return(int i){return corr[i];
};
```

`return` is a keyword. You can't have a function named `return`. Just call it something different. Perhaps `operator[]` is an appropriate operator to overload here?

```
double operator[](int i){ return corr[i]; }
```